# How to ground a kitchen exhaust blower fan?

Tags: electrical, grounding, exhaust-fan, electric-motor, blower

Recently our kitchen exhaust fan stopped working, only humming and not moving. In the kitchen there's a butterfly damper, the exhaust switch is on the vent hood, and the motor and exhaust fan are on the outside of the house. [image: exterior fan]

Did some troubleshooting with the motor, tried cleaning it up but it's DOA. In doing some research it appears this fasco motor is from the 60s(give or take).[image: original motor] I called some manufacturers and found a supposed replacement since that model isn't produced anymore. Unfortunately I didn't look over the diagrams and the replacement didn't have the same mounting bolt holes.

I did some digging and found a replacement motor, ordered it and it fits (it's a fasco d367). But I noticed the new motor has a big warning to ground it, but it doesn't have a ground wire. I don't see the two squares on the label saying it's double insulated.

The original motor didn't have a ground wire either, but the dome and components had a ground wire and so were grounded(partially disconnected in this pic when removing the motor). [image: original wiring]

--

So is the ground wire on the metal dome enough to ground the motor through the case? Or is there something else I need to be doing to properly ground the motor?

Thanks!

Here are some pictures of the new motor for reference. [image: new motor] [image: new motor 2] [image: new motor 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's bolted to a grounded metal case, it's grounded.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- the OP mentioned that there's a ground wire to the dome, and there's one visible near the end of the cable jacket in the updome shot

Comment: Aha. Now I see - the cable is coming through a hole in the dome.

Comment: Awesome, this was a pretty easy solution! Thanks for the help all!